# LINQ: How to perform a conditional sum?

Tags: linq

I have a LINQ Query that creates a new type that contains a days of week and a sum of hours worked. 
My current (incorrect query) looks like this:

```
var resultSet = (from a in events
                 group a by a.Start.DayOfWeek into g
                 select new DaySummary
                 {
                     day = g.Key.ToString(),
                     hoursWorked = g.Any(p => p.Title == "Lunch") ? 0 :
                     Math.Round((g.Sum(
                     p => (Decimal.Parse((p.End - p.Start).TotalMinutes.ToString()))) / 60), 2)
                 }).ToList();
```

Hopefully you can see what Im trying to do. The Any method is not having the effect I'd like however. Basically I want to to sum up the hours worked, but if the title was "lunch" I want it to add 0.

The logic of this is just a little beyond me at the moment.

UPDATE
Ok, Im an idiot. Changes the query to this and it now works. Sorry.

```
var resultSet = (from a in events
                             group a by a.Start.DayOfWeek into g
                             select new DaySummary
                             {
                                 day = g.Key.ToString(),
                                 hoursWorked = Math.Round((g.Where(p => p.Title !="Lunch").
                                 Sum(p => (Decimal.Parse((p.End - p.Start).TotalMinutes.ToString()))) / 60), 2)                                    
                             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems each group is a sequence of 'periods' and you just want to ignore any 'lunch' periods in each calculation. In that case you just need to remove these from the sum using Where.

```
var hours = events
    .GroupBy(e => e.Start.DayOfWeek)
    .Select(g => new DaySummary {
        day = g.Key.ToString(),
        hoursWorked = Math.Round(
            g.Where(p => p.Title != "Lunch")
            .Sum(pd => (Decimal.Parse((pd.End - pd.Start).TotalMinutes.ToString())) / 60), 2)
    }).ToList();
```